# Are there studies clearly illustrating the great discrepancies in programmer productivity?

Tags: productivity, programming-productivity

There exists a widely held (and frequently asserted) belief that there is a very big (relatively to other professions) discrepancy between the top tier software developers and the non-top-tier.

Examples from extremely reputable people include:

- [Paul Graham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Graham_%28computer_programmer%29) (in a bunch of his writings: [[1]](http://www.paulgraham.com/gh.html) , [[2]](http://www.paulgraham.com/wealth.html) )
- Joel Spolsky: ( [[1]](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/HighNotes.html) , [[2]](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/BionicOffice.html) )

  > ... of superstars that produce ten times as much as the merely brilliant software developers.

**Are there any studies supporting this?** (e.g. that a "superstar" programmer would be 10x more productive than merely good programmer or 30-100x than average programmer respectively)

**Just to clarify** - I'm not asking if Joel was correct in naming 100x more productive developers "superstars" - that's his definition. I'm asking if there are enough such 100x more productive developers (100x on average) to warrant a separate class.

Comment: Saeed Dehnadi and Richard Bornat: [The camel has two humps](http://www.eis.mdx.ac.uk/research/PhDArea/saeed/paper1.pdf) and critique by Jeff Attwood: [Separating programming sheep from non programming goats](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/separating-programming-sheep-from-non-programming-goats.html), which mostly focuses on the first programming class, rather than the more seasoned programmers this question is focused on.

Comment: Trying to quantify it is flawed. How do you measure programmers productivity? If programmer A finishes product in 5 days, and programmer B also finishes product in 5 days, but he has brilliant idea on how to optimize the process, which also makes final product 1000 times faster, then how much "more productive" is programmer B, than programmer A?

Comment: @Vartec - I wouldn't say that "trying to quantify" is "flawed". It's **difficult** to quatify, with most of the trivial/easy methodologies easily gamed or simply poor for the reasons you stated and more. But that doesn't mean that it's impossible to quantify, or that the desire to quantify in and out of itself is flawed.

Comment: @DVK: still, it's flawed, as 10 interns will be way more effective making cookie-cut form interfaces, than 1 brilliant programmer at same job. In fact even one inter will be probably more effective. On the other hand 1 brilliant programmer will be infinitely more effective at designing complex, scalable system, as 10 clueless interns will just fail to deliver at all.

Comment: @DVK - It is a subjective criteria.  So Jeff has defined a Superstar as someone who produces 10x more than a brilliant programmer whom he has defined as someone who produces 10x more than an average programmer.  I disagree with that definition... but that is his definition.  Unless you are skeptical of the claim that one programmer could possible produce 100x more code than the average I do not see how this could be answered.

Comment: @Chad - you are correct - that is EXCACTLY the claim I'm skeptical about. Namely that there are strata of productivity with such wide dispersion between them.

Comment: btw. I do remember reading about IBM's studies about years of programmers' experience vs productivity, showing that seasoned programmer would be 10x as effective as newbie with < 6 moths experience.

Comment: I seem to remember first encountering this statistic in the Psychology of Computer Programming by Gerald M. Weinberg. If I remember correctly it was based on research at IBM. (It was a library copy from perhaps 25 years ago, so I don't have it to hand). It may also have referred to fully-debugged, documented code. (Remember somebody introducing a bug can cause days of work for other people trying to find it - the worst programmers in my experience actually have negative productivity!)

Comment: Is it possible to measure the productivity of lone programmers as individuals at all at least for big modern software projects? Don't you have to evaluate the whole team? Even an individually productive programmer can be brought low by a poor team, poor leadership or poor coordination.

Comment: I recently wrote a column criticizing this interpretation of the data: http://www.sdtimes.com/CODE_WATCH_THE_MYTH_OF_10X_SUPERPROGRAMMERS/By_Larry_O_Brien/About_SUPERPROGRAMMERS/36247 The most important point is that, even with the very few studies and there flaws and there questionable universality, it's not 10x between best and median, but between best and worst. I argue there is significant positive skew (excellent developers "fight a headwind" of complexity, communication, etc.) that creates a "long tail" of incompetence, and a shorter tail of excellence.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination: http://retractionwatch.com/2014/07/18/the-camel-doesnt-have-two-humps-programming-aptitude-test-canned-for-overzealous-conclusion/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Common source for these claims is [Peopleware](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0932633439). The authors claim that while conducting programming competitions called Coding War Games during the 1980s they found that:

> Three  rules  of thumb seem to apply whenever you measure variations in performance over a sample of individuals:
>
> - Count on the best people outperforming the worst by about 10:1.
> - Count on the best performer being about 2.5 times better than the median performer.
> - Count on the half that are better-than-median performers outdoing the other half by more than 2:1.

More modern source is Steve McConnell's article in "What Does 10x Mean? Measuring Variations in Programmer Productivity" [Making Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596808321) where the author refers to several other sources that are mostly from the 1980s. If someone wants to hunt these studies down, the sources are:

- [Boehm et al. 2000] Boehm, Barry, et al. 2000. Software Cost Estimation with Cocomo II. Boston: Addison-Wesley.
- [Boehm and Papaccio 1988] Boehm, Barry W., and Philip N. Papaccio. 1988. Understanding
  and Controlling Software Costs. IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering 14(10): 1462–1477.
- [Curtis 1981] Curtis, Bill. 1981. Substantiating Programmer Variability. Proceedings of the IEEE 69(7): 846.
- [DeMarco and Lister 1985] DeMarco, Tom, and Timothy Lister. 1985. Programmer
  Performance and the Effects of the Workplace. Proceedings of the 8th International Conference on Software Engineering: 268–272.
- [Mills 1983] Mills, Harlan D. 1983. Software Productivity. Boston: Little, Brown.
- [Card 1987] Card, David N. 1987. A Software Technology Evaluation Program. Information and Software Technology 29(6): 291–300.
- [Curtis et al. 1986] Curtis, Bill, et al. 1986. Software Psychology: The Need for an
  Interdisciplinary Program. Proceedings of the IEEE 74(8): 1092–1106.
- [Valett and McGarry 1989] Valett, J., and F.E. McGarry. 1989. A Summary of Software
  Measurement Experiences in the Software Engineering Laboratory. Journal of Systems and
  Software 9(2): 137–148.

For [interesting discussion on programming ability related to salary check Stackoverflow podcast #77](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/podcast-77/).

Comment: Coding wars is a very good data source, though probably only for upper end of the spectrum. I don't think mediocre programmers enrolled, though not 100% sure (was before my time - the only things I ever competed in were ACM contests).

Comment: @DVK - I do not accept that what was true in the days of 8 bit processors/compilers and < 256k ram is true today.  The productivity tools that exist now enable even mediocre programmers to produce effective code that executes complex functionality relatively easily.  In the 80's we basically had macros for our text editors and cheat sheets.

Comment: @Chad - it's not about the tools. It's about understanding and designing abstractions. Src: Joel Spolsky :)

Comment: @DVK - And I am saying that as someone who does this for a living since the days of 8 bit processors that what was an average programmer in the 80's could be far more productive with today's tools especially the internet.

Comment: @Chad - I donno... so far, only ~30% or less of my own SO questions were answered to my satisfaction :))))   Most were not useful/helpful at all. And I would posit that the tools give MORE of an edge to a good programmer than a bad one, introducing extra leverage. Just my theory (my first "tool" was a Sinclair Z80 Basic :)

Comment: @DVK - But this is talking about quantity not quality.  With VS and asp.net an amateur can whip up a fairly functional site with database connectivity quickly and by writing very little if any code that hits a database and has a fairly secure login functionality.  To me the senior knows how to go beyond that and fix the holes those types of solutions leave.  The superstar creates Google/Facebook etc.  The superstar does not work for your company you work for him.

Comment: Laurent Bossavit criticizes McConnell's citations here: http://morendil.github.com/folklore.html McConnell responds here: http://goo.gl/AEpul (FWIW, I've read every one of the sources and feel that all have questionable aspects: students, very short durations, "apples to oranges" language levels, etc.)

Comment: @Chad Yup--I had a very dramatic example of this several years back.  A guy who knew little of coding but had managed to produce a functional program for a simple task--but was totally stumped on saving one integer between sessions.

Comment: Given that this is about "programming competition", what does "performance" mean in this context? Being better than others? Because winning competition 10 times more often is something *completely different* than being 10 times more productive.

Comment: I disagree with your numbers.  My experiences with programming, and this no doubt applies to many other situations, a bad performer can slow down a development quite easily; and in programming field at least these programmers do get highered due to the lack of developers relative to number of jobs and the inability or limited effort put into screening competence over raw years of work.  Thus I would say the best performer out performance the worst performer infinitely since the worst performer at any large project likely is costing man-hours.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a well documented study. Individual productivity was not the goal of this paper, but there is data that's related to your question. A copy of the paper can be found [here](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/jccpprtTR.pdf)

On page 22, there's a box graph of hours needed to complete the program by language. If we assume programmer productivity to be time to complete a given programming task, then we have a maximum range of productivity of ~4 hours - 63 hours within Java. We can say that the best programmer did perform 10 times faster than the worst.

Original paper:

An empirical comparison of C, C++, Java,
Perl, Python, Rexx, and Tcl
for a search/string-processing program by Lutz Prechelt (2000)

If you were interested, the paper includes the raw data, and you can perform your own analysis on the distribution. The distribution would tell you approximately **how many programmers you would need to say that the best programmer is 100x more productive than the worst**.

Comment: Prechelt is a good researcher. I would caution, though, that a developer who excels at one task might not do so well consistently -- familiarity with the task versus pursuing dead ends seems to me an important part of the job. And perhaps over many tasks developers regress toward the mean.