# Is it true that the best programmer in the office is 30 times faster than the worst programmer in the office?

Tags: programming, programming-productivity

I was once told by a professor at a prestigious university (paraphrase):

> In the average software development workplace, the best programmer is 30 times faster than the
>   worst programmer.  So if it takes the office's best programmer
>   one day to write some particular code, it will take that same office's
>   worst programmer an entire month to write the same code.  These two
>   programmers will often be making roughly the same salary.

Is this true?  Are there any references or studies to corroborate this?

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me at all if true, although a bit hard to prove. Anyone paying these 2 fictitious programmers the same salary probably wont stay in business too long.

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7559/are-there-studies-clearly-illustrating-the-great-discrepancies-in-programmer-pro

Comment: Define "good" and "bad".  Is a programmer that turns out 1000 lines of crap a day better than one who turns out 10 lines of good quality, well-documented, properly tested code?

Comment: @GordonM I am talking in terms of variable hours in exchange for equal functionality. Nothing else.

Comment: Time taken depends an awful lot on the difficulty of a problem. Any healthy person can run 100 meters in three times the world record time. Many people cannot climb five meters up a rope in any time. For a hard enough problem, some programmers can do it and some can't. For a simple problem, the ratio should be less extreme.